# hay alguna forma de recorrer los elementos que no están visibles dentro del código html o de hacer visible el código con alguna instrucción

Tags: vba

soy Luis, estoy programando hace muy poco tiempo una macro en código módulo visual basic de excel, con la que manejo una pagina web, utilizando IE11, no se si tendrán el tiempo, como para ayudarme.

pero estoy desesperado y por mas que busco propiedades, métodos e instrucciones en internet, no logro resolver mi problema.

el tema es que necesito recorrer los elementos (div) de una pagina web, para lograr hacer click, en un item, dentro de un combobox, todo esto de forma automática, sin intervención del usuario.

la forma con la que logro hacerlo, en estado paso a paso de depuración es la siguiente:

```
Dim HTMLDoc As HTMLDocument
Dim oHTML_Element As Object

Set HTMLDoc = ie.document
Set oHTML_Element = ie.document.getElementsByTagName(«class»)

Dim itemEle As Object

for Each oHTML_Element In HTMLDoc.getElementsByTagName(«div»)
    If oHTML_Element.getAttribute(«class») = «dijitReset dijitMenuItem» Then
    If oHTML_Element.getAttribute(«item») = 1 then
 oHTML_Element.Click
    End If
    End If
    Exit For
Next
```

como comente, de esa forma logro llegar al item que necesito y hacer click automático, pero eso, solo si intervengo haciendo click directamente sobre la flecha ▼ del combobox, porque descubrí, que el elemento div y la class (dijitPopup dijitComboBoxMenuPopup) no se muestran en el código HTML hasta que no se haga click en algún item del combobox.

hay alguna forma de recorrer los elementos que no están visibles dentro del código html o de hacer visible el código con alguna instrucción.

quedo atento a sus comentarios, de antemano gracias.

[image: IMAGEN ANTES DE HACER CLICK EN EL BOTON DEL COMBO]

[image: IMAGEN DESPUES DE HACER CLICK EN EL BOTON DEL COMBO Y AHI RECIEN APARECE DENTRO DEL CODIGO HTML EL DIV dijitPopup dijitComboBoxMenuPopup]

Comment: Analiza a ver si hay algún evento asociado al control que deba ser activado para mostrar esos elementos invisibles. Sin ver la página web ni nada, es imposible saberlo.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! No termino de entender tu edicion a la pregunta.. si el combo se carga despues de que hace la seleccion, entonces capaz los datos todavia no estan.. en ese caso, tenes que analizar como funciona el combo.

Comment: hola y gracias por darse el tiempo de revisar mi publicación, en realidad lo que no se carga es el código HTML <div class="dijitPopup dijitComboBoxMenuPopup" id="widget_itemFolderComboBox_dropdown" el cual contiene los items y que de esos item quiero seleccionar automaticamente el numero 1, pero no se puede recorrer, ya que el código se genera de forma dinamica.

Comment: Si se genera en forma dinamica, la respuesta es no, no lo vas a poder recorrer.. porque no existe. Hasta tanto no exista, no va a aparecer... entonces tenes que hacer que aparezca... Para eso, te dejaron un comentario

Comment: ok, pondré el foco en revisar cual es el evento que activa el div dinámico. ¿por casualidad hay alguna forma de revisar el código html, como en visual basic paso a paso por las instrucciones y no morir en el intento? gracias maestros!!!